# Is it right to ask: "Have you been back in the area?"

Tags: questions

Is it right to ask: "Have you been back in the area?"

For example, the question is directed to someone who went on a vacation in a different country - and we want to know if the person came back.

What other good option do I have to ask something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person you're asking lives in the same town/city, you can say "Are you back in town?"

If the person you're asking lives in another town/city, you can say "Have you made it home yet?" or "Are you back in *town name* now?"

Comment: Hello, Carrie. Do you think this question appropriate on a site aimed at linguists? Answering such questions sends a wrong message to the (potential) user base.

Comment: Hello, Edwin. I'm not sure what is the issue with my question